# How do I get ItemStatus from a UITestControl?

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

The [UI Automation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) has a base class, [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx), that has a property, [ItemStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.itemstatus%28VS.100%29.aspx), that can be used to store arbitrary strings. I'm trying to get that property from the Visual Studio 2010 [Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726%28VS.100%29.aspx) base class, [UITestControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Coded UI Tests generated code for `WpfControl`. It has a property, NativeElement. This property is an `AutomationElement`.

```
public abstract class WpfControl : UITestControl
{
    ...

    public virtual object NativeElement
    {
        get
        {
            return ((object)(this.GetProperty(UITestControlProperties.Common.NativeElement)));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You can write an extension method to cast it and get ItemStatus.

```
public static string GetItemStatus(this WpfControl control)
{
    var automationElement = (AutomationElement)control.NativeElement;
    return automationElement.Current.ItemStatus;
}
```

I am not certain why NativeElement is recorded as an `object` (which makes the getter cast redundant). All WPF controls' NativeElement are of type `AutomationElement`. I would suggest editing the generated code and simply calling `control.NativeElement.Current.ItemStatus` directly.