# How to access NativeElement items for CodedUI controls?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

For any codedUI control while debugging(Quickwatch) I can traverse though all the elements in NativeElement, but couldn't find any method or way to use them while coding.

NativeElement property for any control always returns a ***string***.

How can I get values of elements in **NativeElement** [image]in code?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849001/how-do-i-get-itemstatus-from-a-uitestcontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add reference Microsoft.mshtml then you can cast your UIElements' native elements to the appropriate mshtml interface.

```
mshtml.HTMLDivElement nativeElement = dialogs[0].NativeElement as mshtml.HTMLDivElement;
```

Some brain food: all recorded elements in the CUIT's UIMap are derived from the UITestControl. UITestControl implements the NativeElement property. The NativeElement's return type is object because there are multiple technologies to record UIElements (like MSAA or UIA) and the returned object is actually a COM object which is accessible by its provided interface. So you have to cast the native element to said interface to access its properties and methods.

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for. Now it feels like getting a more powerful gun in a game. Thanks.